# PATH environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, path, executable

If a command's executable file resides in a directory that is not defined in your PATH environment variable, how can you still execute it?

Comment: specify the full path....

Answer (score 1):

Use the full path of the executable file.

If you are unsure of its full path, you may use the find command, such as this search for `sed` :

```
  find / -iname "*sed*"
```

Then you would use the full path when executing it:

```
  /bin/sed ...
```